# Creative Short Word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I successfully run the longest word function which search for the longest word in an array:

```
var array = ["dog", "cat", "horse"];
var largest = 0;
var longestWord = " ";

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length <= largest) {
    largest = array[i].length;
    longestWord = array[i];
    } 
}
console.log("The longest word is "+ longestWord);
console.log("The length of the word is " + largest);
```

Trying to be a bit smart, I sneak in and try to reverse the conditional operator to get the SHORTEST word in the array:

```
var array2 = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hsalsaaaaa"];
var shortest = 0;
var shortestWord = " ";

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].length < shortest) { // if an item length is less than 0 then
    shortest = array2[i].length; // shortest is equal to the length of the item
    shortestWord = array2[i]; // then " " will be the item itself;
    } 
}
console.log("The shortest word is "+ shortestWord);
console.log("The length of the word is " + shortest);
```

But this code keeps sending me 0 and blank word. Any idea what to tweak here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well... what's smaller than 0?

Comment: is it ok, to get only one shortest word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code fails is because there is no word smaller than `" "`.

Start with

```
var shortestWord = array2[0];
```

Now, iterate from the first element onwards.

```
for (var i = 1; i < array2.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

I prefer this to `Infinity` because you reduce your iterations by 1.

---

```js
var array2 = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hsalsaaaaa"];
var shortestWord = array2[0];

for (var i = 1; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].length < shortestWord.length) { // if an item length is less than 0 then
        shortestWord = array2[i]; // then " " will be the item itself;
    } 
}
console.log("The shortest word is "+ shortestWord);
console.log("The length of the word is " + shortestWord.length);
```

I've taken the liberty to remove `shortest` because it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use as start value instead of zero, [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), this is the greatest possible value.

```js
var array2 = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hsalsaaaaa"],
    shortest = Infinity,
    shortestWord,
    i

for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].length < shortest) { // if an item length is less than 0 then
        shortest = array2[i].length; // shortest is equal to the length of the item
        shortestWord = array2[i]; // then " " will be the item itself;
    }
}
console.log("The shortest word is " + shortestWord);
console.log("The length of the word is " + shortest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the initialization `var shortest = 0;` to something like `var shortest = 100000;`. Else nothing would be smaller than 0. Here 100000 signifies any value that is very large and the words would not be that large in length for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating two variables? `shortestWord` is enough:

```
var arr = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hsalsaaaaa"];
var shortestWord = arr[0]

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if(arr[i].length < shortestWord.length) shortestWord = arr[i]; 

console.log("The shortest word is", shortestWord, ",length is", shortestWord.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array2 = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hsalsaaaaa"];
var shortest = 0;
var shortestWord = " ";

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].length <= shortest) { 
    shortest = array2[i].length; 
    shortestWord = array2[i];
    } 
}
console.log("The shortest word is "+ shortestWord);
console.log("The length of the word is " + shortest);

That was because your if condition was wrong
```